# OSX Sierra unlock-keychain stopped working within ssh

Tags: macos

We connect to a MAC with SSH and run a script wich contains the line

```
security unlock-keychain -p XXX
```

But since we updated the machine to "macOS Sierra" we get an error

```
security: SecKeychainUnlock <NULL>: The user name or passphrase you entered is not correct.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/jirsbek/SSH-keys-in-macOS-Sierra-keychain

Answer (score 5):

When you connect via SSH, it looks like `security` doesn't know about the logged-in user Keychains: if you issue a `security list-keychains` command, you'll only see the System keychain, instead of the user's keychains.

What you need to do is specify the keychain file you want to unlock:

```
security unlock-keychain -p XXX "keychain_path_here"
```

Where `keychain_path_here` is something like `/Users/username/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to specify a keychain to unlock each time you ssh into a machine, you can create an ssh key and copy it to the destination machine:

```
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id username@remote.host
```

After copying your ssh id to the host, you'll be able to unlock the default login keychain for the user you're logging in with. If you have multiple user accounts you need to log in with, you can ssh-copy-id for each of the users.

(ssh-copy-id isn't included in macOS by default. You can install it with homebrew)